# sorl-thumbnail giving incorrect url on refresh

Tags: python, django, upload, image-uploading, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to resize images before uploading them and then sending back url as json value.

This is how my model looks like:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
     picid = models.AutoField(null=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     large = ImageField(upload_to=Helper.createPhotoName)
     med = ImageField(upload_to=Helper.createPhotoName)
     small = ImageField(upload_to=Helper.createPhotoName)

def save(Self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
     self.med = get_thumbnail(self.large, '150x150', crop='center', quality=99)
     self.small = get_thumbnail(self.large, '80x80', crop='center', quality=99)
```

After the user uploads the image, it saves it into the model, gets the url and sends it back to the client.

```
   self.f = request.Files['file']
   usr = User.objects.get(pk=self.uid)
   pic = usr.picture_set.create(large=self.f, med=self.f, small=self.f)

   self.data['med'] = pic.med.url
   self.data['small'] = pic.small.url
```

Afterwards, in another view, saved image is always looked for in database whenever the page is reloaded or revisited to show the older image and an option to change it.

```
  pic = Picture.objects.get(user=uid)
  self.data['photo'] = {
                      'small': pic.small.url,
                       'med': pic.med.url,
                      'silh': False
                     }
```

While first time I get the right url but second time I am getting a wrong one. I get 3 images for each upload in my `upload_to` path and 3 resized images in a cache directory at `MEDIA_ROOT`. In picture table `upload_to` path is being saved not the cache one, while the resized images lie in cache directory.

In thumbnail_kvstore table, I can see the path of resized image as `name` dict key. Just after uploading I get an url of the cache, but on refresh I get url of the upload_to path and I am not able to get resized image.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `save()` **after** the setting of the thumnbail fields:

```
def save(Self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.med = get_thumbnail(self.large, '150x150', crop='center',
                                                            quality=99).name
     self.small = get_thumbnail(self.large, '80x80', crop='center',
                                                            quality=99).name
     super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It gives `AttributeError: 'ImageFile' object has no attribute '_committed'`

Comment: This error occurs because the `ImageFile` from `sorl-thumnbail` is not  a subclass of the django `FieldFile`. Try to assign a string filename to the instance field.  Note the `.name` attributes in the updated answer.

Comment: after doing that it's not at all creating thumbnails and just a single original image is stored and everything breaks.